# In Gradle build, start Spring boot application, run tests and then stop the Spring boot application

Tags: spring, gradle, spring-boot, integration-testing

With my Gradle build I want to start my Spring Boot application, run some tests and then shutdown the Spring boot application. First I try just to start the server and then shutdown, leaving out the tests for now.

Part of my build.gradle file looks like this

```
bootRun {
    systemProperties = System.properties
}

task shutdown(type: org._10ne.gradle.rest.RestTask) {
    httpMethod = 'post'
    uri = 'http://localhost:8080/shutdown'
}

task integrationTest() {
    dependsOn bootRun
    finalizedBy shutdown
}
```

I start the build from the command line like this

```
gradle integrationTest -Dendpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

The build starts the Spring Boot application but it is not proceeding (of course) to the shutdown task. I can run the shutdown task separately and it will take down the Spring Boot app.

But, how can I get the server to run and shutdown in the same build?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it will work with a task like `bootRun`, but I think you're looking for something like a [ParallelizableTask](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/ParallelizableTask.html)

Also you would have to pass the `--parallel` command line option.